# Recursively find all possible paths with a set number of moves and varying options at each node

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, path-finding

I have a 5 x 5 grid. Each grid is an object with an id, a value (initially empty), and a possible move set. The possible move set is that given any location on the grid it can move to any new position that is either -16,-21,-12,-3,3,12,21,16 of the current grid id but the position cannot be less than 1 or above 25 (since the grid is 25 positions) and cannot be already occupied.
The objective is to fill the whole grid with numbers 1-25 with the number being the number of the move that positioned there. But there isn't necessarily only one route per starting position so I would like to find all possible paths for a given starting point on the grid.

I have the grid creation working correctly,  as well as selecting from the possible options to the next. My issue is concerning several aspects, the rollback to choose a different path if the chosen path was a dead-end or rolling back several levels of selection if there is repeated failure. Additionally finding all paths after one path has been found.

[image]

As seen above, for example, if I start at the center at 13 I can move to 2 then 17, etc. If I get stuck I would then move back to the previous point and try another option. I would try all possible options at that level but if it's a dead-end I would move back to another level. The idea is to find a path that uses ALL 25 cells

Given this below code. I can get to the 17th round out of 25 in the selection but I cannot seem to wrap my head around back tracking further to find a 1 complete path let alone multiple:

```
grid_size = 25

grid = {}
grid_list = []
#initialise grid details
pos_moves=[-16,-21,-12,-3,3,12,21,16 ]
### give all possible moves for this

x = 1
while x <= grid_size:
    moves =[]
    for i in pos_moves:
        if 0 < (x + i) < 26:
            moves.append(x + i)
    #print(moves)
    grid[x] ={ "id" : x, "moves" : moves}
    grid_list.append({"id":x})
    x += 1
    
print(grid)

visited = {}

next_location = int
round_level = 1


def choose_path(current_location):
    global round_level
    global next_location
    options = grid[current_location]['moves']
    print("################## Round " + str(round_level) + "##################\n" +
          "current grid area: " + str(current_location) + "\n"
          "current options: " + str(options) + "\n"
                  )
    next_location = options.pop(0)
    if next_location not in visited:
        visited[next_location] = options
        print("Remaining options: " + str(options) + " chosen option" + str(next_location))
        print("visited:  " + str(visited))
        round_level += 1
        return choose_path(next_location)
    elif next_location in visited:
        if len(options) == 0:
            print("Visited:   " + ",".join(str(key) for key in visited))
            print("stopping here")
        else:
            next_location = options.pop(0)
            return  choose_path(next_location)



choose_path(13)
```

Comment: "rollback" is often called [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) and is commonly implemented using a recursive depth-first search (DFS). In your implementation, you'll want to record each solution that is found, and continue the DFS until there are no more paths to search.

Comment: Should also be noted that if the allowed moves are all **even** numbers, then you'll never be able to reach odd positions starting from an even position, and vice versa.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for the catch regarding the even numbers. An error on my part. fixed

Comment: @user3386109 I added code to further clarify